# Restrict client-side people picker in SharePoint to single line of text

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

I want to use a people picker (client-side, created using JavaScript function  `SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper`) that only allows one person and is only restricted to a single line of text.

There is an option to allow only one user:

```
schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
```

However, all it does is merely shows a warning message when more than one user is selected. The field still becomes a two-line field (like in the picture), which breaks the layout.

[image: sharepoint people picker]

What would be a good way to never allow this field to span two lines of text? It must be restricted to one line only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Over which control you have applied this `PeoplePicker`?

I too have done this using `div` structure. Which never allows me to break the control into `Multiline`. It always stay `Single line`.

Here is what I am using:

```
<div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
```

Comment: It's just over a normal div, like in your example.

Answer (score -1):

Use this CSS to set the height:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .sp-peoplepicker-topLevel{
        height:auto !important;
    }
</style>
```